# How to find /open file from PC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, photo

you experts probably knowing the easyiest ways to open/find a file from asp.net mvc application.

could you tell me please how to do that, if i want for example to find and upload a photo from my PC.

Thanks and take care,
Ragims

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/Fileuploadinaspnetmvc06292009030526AM/Fileuploadinaspnetmvc.aspx) may help you.

> The article will show how to upload a
>   file from client to server location in
>   ASP.Net MVC application in 5 easy
>   steps.

Answer (score 0):

Two samples:

- [example one](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/03/file-uploads-with-mvc-framework.html)
- [example two with unit testing](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple HTML file input in your view will suffice:

```
<input type="file" name="MyFile" id="MyFile" />
```

Then accept the file in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase myFile)
{
    // save or process file here...

    return View();
}
```

Also, remember to set `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">` in your form.